# Dynamically assign new members to a pre-defined Case Team

Tags: case-teams

I have a pre-defined case team called `Specialists` that I want to dynamically add via code a  user named `Fred Fubar`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some key points

- A predefined case team is defined by the object `CaseTeamTemplate` ([reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_caseteamtemplate.htm?q=caseteamtemplate))
- The relevant object to construct is `CaseTeamTemplateMember` ([reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_caseteamtemplatemember.htm?q=caseteamtemplatemember)).  This is a junction record between a `User` and the `CaseTeamTemplate` for a given role.

So, the Apex would look like this

```
User u = [SELECT Id, Name from User WHERE Name = 'Fred Fubar'][0];
CaseTeamTemplate ctt = [SELECT Id, Name FROM CaseTeamTemplate WHERE Name = 'Specialists'][0];
CaseTeamRole ctr = [SELECT Id, Name FROM CaseTeamRole WHERE Name = 'IT Specialist'][0];

insert new CaseTeamTemplateMember(MemberId = u.Id, 
                                  TeamTemplateId = ctt.Id, 
                                  TeamRoleId = ctr.Id );
```